# Unable to Load data with ORM-LITE android with one-many

Tags: android, ormlite

I am creating an android app which can save data locally. I have used orm- lite to persist data

Here is my model class structure

```
public class Site implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField
    int siteRecordId;
    @DatabaseField
    int recorderId;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteName;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteDatum;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteEasting;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteLatitude;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteLongtitude;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteNorthing;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteLocationMethod;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteZone;
    @DatabaseField
    String siteType;
    @DatabaseField
    String horizantalAccuracy;
    @DatabaseField
    String landFormPattern;
    @DatabaseField
    String landFormElement;
    @DatabaseField
    String vagetation;
    @DatabaseField
    String landUse;
    @DatabaseField
    String distanceToWater;
    @DatabaseField
    String howToSite;
    @DatabaseField
    String primaryReport;
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    ForeignCollection<Parameter> parameters;


    public Site(){

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getSiteRecordId() {
        return siteRecordId;
    }

    public void setSiteRecordId(int siteRecordId) {
        this.siteRecordId = siteRecordId;
    }

    public int getRecorderId() {
        return recorderId;
    }

    public void setRecorderId(int recorderId) {
        this.recorderId = recorderId;
    }

    public String getSiteName() {
        return siteName;
    }

    public void setSiteName(String siteName) {
        this.siteName = siteName;
    }

    public String getSiteDatum() {
        return siteDatum;
    }

    public void setSiteDatum(String siteDatum) {
        this.siteDatum = siteDatum;
    }

    public String getSiteEasting() {
        return siteEasting;
    }

    public void setSiteEasting(String siteEasting) {
        this.siteEasting = siteEasting;
    }

    public String getSiteLatitude() {
        return siteLatitude;
    }

    public void setSiteLatitude(String siteLatitude) {
        this.siteLatitude = siteLatitude;
    }

    public String getSiteLongtitude() {
        return siteLongtitude;
    }

    public void setSiteLongtitude(String siteLongtitude) {
        this.siteLongtitude = siteLongtitude;
    }

    public String getSiteNorthing() {
        return siteNorthing;
    }

    public void setSiteNorthing(String siteNorthing) {
        this.siteNorthing = siteNorthing;
    }

    public String getSiteLocationMethod() {
        return siteLocationMethod;
    }

    public void setSiteLocationMethod(String siteLocationMethod) {
        this.siteLocationMethod = siteLocationMethod;
    }

    public String getSiteZone() {
        return siteZone;
    }

    public void setSiteZone(String siteZone) {
        this.siteZone = siteZone;
    }

    public String getSiteType() {
        return siteType;
    }

    public void setSiteType(String siteType) {
        this.siteType = siteType;
    }

    public String getHorizantalAccuracy() {
        return horizantalAccuracy;
    }

    public void setHorizantalAccuracy(String horizantalAccuracy) {
        this.horizantalAccuracy = horizantalAccuracy;
    }

    public String getLandFormPattern() {
        return landFormPattern;
    }

    public void setLandFormPattern(String landFormPattern) {
        this.landFormPattern = landFormPattern;
    }

    public String getLandFormElement() {
        return landFormElement;
    }

    public void setLandFormElement(String landFormElement) {
        this.landFormElement = landFormElement;
    }

    public String getVagetation() {
        return vagetation;
    }

    public void setVagetation(String vagetation) {
        this.vagetation = vagetation;
    }

    public String getLandUse() {
        return landUse;
    }

    public void setLandUse(String landUse) {
        this.landUse = landUse;
    }

    public String getDistanceToWater() {
        return distanceToWater;
    }

    public void setDistanceToWater(String distanceToWater) {
        this.distanceToWater = distanceToWater;
    }

    public String getHowToSite() {
        return howToSite;
    }

    public void setHowToSite(String howToSite) {
        this.howToSite = howToSite;
    }

    public String getPrimaryReport() {
        return primaryReport;
    }

    public void setPrimaryReport(String primaryReport) {
        this.primaryReport = primaryReport;
    }

    public ForeignCollection<Parameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(ForeignCollection<Parameter> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }



}


package com.jbmdigital.model;
```

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;

public class Parameter implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
int id;
@DatabaseField
int  categoryId;
@DatabaseField
int siteId;
@DatabaseField
String paramValue;
@DatabaseField
int clonable;
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "site")
    Site site;


public Parameter(){

}

public Parameter(int categoryId,String paramValue,int clonable,Site site){
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.paramValue = paramValue;
    this.clonable = clonable;
    this.site = site;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}
public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}
public String getParamValue() {
    return paramValue;
}
public void setParamValue(String paramValue) {
    this.paramValue = paramValue;
}
public int getClonable() {
    return clonable;
}
public void setClonable(int clonable) {
    this.clonable = clonable;
}
public Site getSite() {
    return site;
}
public void setSite(Site site) {
    this.site = site;
}
```

}

Here is my ormlite_config.txt

#

## generated on 2013/05/09 09:13:AM

#

dataClass=com.jbmdigital.model.Site
tableName=site

## --table-fields-start--

## --field-start--

fieldName=id
generatedId=true

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteRecordId

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=recorderId

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteName
indexName=

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteDatum

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteEasting

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteLatitude

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteLongtitude

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteNorthing

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteLocationMethod

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteZone

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteType

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=horizantalAccuracy

## --field-end-

## --field-start--

fieldName=landFormPattern

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=landFormElement

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=vagetation

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=landUse

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=distanceToWater

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=howToSite

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=primaryReport

## --field-end--

## --table-fields-end--

## --table-end--

## --table-start--

dataClass=com.jbmdigital.model.Parameter
tableName=parameter

## --table-fields-start--

## --field-start--

fieldName=id
generatedId=true

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=siteId

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=categoryId

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=paramValue

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=site
foreign=true

## --field-end--

## --field-start--

fieldName=clonable

## --field-end--

## --table-fields-end--

## --table-end--

#

Here is my Activity class

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------



DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                RuntimeExceptionDao<Site, Integer> simpleSiteDao = db.getSimpleSiteDataDao();
                RuntimeExceptionDao<Parameter, Integer> simpleParamDao = db.getSimpleaParameterDataDao();
                simpleSiteDao.create(site);

                Site accountResult = simpleSiteDao.queryForId(site.getId());

                for (Parameter parameter : parameterList) {
                    parameter.setSite(accountResult);
                    simpleParamDao.create(parameter);

                }
                List<Site> sites= simpleSiteDao.queryForAll();

                int index = sites.size()-1;
                 Log.d("count",""+sites.get(index).getParameters().size());
```

But if i tried to print the log it gives me null point exception. I think i dont get the ParameterList according Site instance.

Comment: Wow.  You need to _significantly_ shorten this post.  Samples of everything instead of the whole files.  Use pastebin.com or something if you need to post the entire thing.

Comment: And after posting all that stuff, you neglect the critical piece of information.  If you get an exception, you should show the exception stack trace and explain where in the code it is occurring.